# Set trigger to change column value based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two columns: A and B, they are on different tables.

I want to set up a trigger that changes column A value to a default string whenever i make B null. How can i do it on MYSQL? I have no experience with triggers :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TRIGGERS EXAMPLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF NEW.amount is NULL THEN
         SET NEW.item = 0;        
     END IF;
 END;
```